# Cassandra Cannot achieve consistency level SERIAL

Tags: cassandra, database-replication, consistency, cassandra-3.0

I recently discovered that if you use conditional transactions in Cassandra, then it will default to using a SERIAL consistency for those transactions.

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/lightweight-transactions-in-cassandra-2-0

However I cannot figure out how to set up my replication factor and number of nodes so that conditional transactions succeed even with a single node down. I would like to have a replication factor of 2.

I have tried with `replication_factor` of 1 and 2 with a 5 node cluster. Do I need more nodes? Is there a configuration somewhere I'm missing? My keyspace configuration below. I've experienced this on Cassandra 3.5 and 3.9.

`CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS reptest WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor':2};`

Comment: can try using network topology strategy instead of simple strategy? Theres some issues with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SERIAL` consistency level corresponds to `QUORUM` when it comes to the number of nodes that have to acknowledge the operation. The minimum replication factor that would still allow to compensate for a single dead node with QUORUM would be 3 (with at least 2 out of 3 nodes alive).

Comment: Can you explain why a replication factor of 3 works but a replication factor of 2 does not? As far as I can tell they should both require the same number of nodes for a quorom.

Comment: If quorum requires 2 nodes, but your replication factor is only 2, then both of them need to be alive. With replication factor 3, one node can be down to still meet the 2 node quorum.

Comment: Right, but if I have a 3 node cluster with replication factor of 2, shouldn't Cassandra tolerate the loss of a single node?

Comment: The 3rd node is irrelevant if you only replicate the data across 2 of the 3 nodes.